# How do I manage an access token, when storing in local storage is not an option?

Tags: reactjs, access-token, laravel-passport

I have a ReactJS app running in browser, which needs access to my backend laravel-passport API server. So, I am in control of all code on both client and server side, and can change it as I please.

In my react app, the user logs in with their username and password, and if this is successful, the app recieves a [personal access token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#personal-access-tokens) which grants access to the users data. If I store this token in local storage, the app can now access this users data by appending the token to outgoing requests.

But I do not want to save the access token in local storage, since this is not secure. How do I do this?

Here is what I have tried:

In the [laravel passport documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport), there is a guide on how to automatically store the access token in a [cookie](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript). I believe this requires the app to be on the same origin, but I cannot get this to work. When testing locally, I run the app on localhost:4000, but the API is run on my-app.localhost. Could this be a reason why laravel passport does not make a cookie with the token, although they technically both have origin localhost?

OAuth has a page on where to [store tokens](https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens). I tried the three options for ["If backend is present"](https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens#if-a-backend-is-present), but they seem to focus on how the authorization flow rather than how to specifically store the token.

Here's the relevant parts of my code (of course, feel free to ask for more if needed):

From my react app:

```
const tokenData = await axios.post(this.props.backendUrl + '/api/loginToken', { email: 'myEmail', password: 'myPassword' })
    console.log('token data: ', tokenData)
    const personalAccessToken = tokenData.data.success.token;
    var config = {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + personalAccessToken
    };
    const user = await axios.get(this.props.backendUrl + '/api/user', config);
```

From the controller class ApiController:

```
    public function loginToken()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])) {
            $user = Auth::user();

            $success['token'] = $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
            return response()->json(['success' => $success], 200);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorised'], 401);
        }
    }
```

and the loginToken function is called from the /api/loginToken route.

Expected and actual results:

Ideally, I would love to have the token saved in a cookie like in [the passport documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript), so I don't even have to attach the token to outgoing requests from the react app, but I'm not sure that this is even possible. Perhaps with third party cookies?

Else, I'd just like to find some way to store the token securely (for example in a cookie?), and then append it to outgoing calls from the react app.

Comment: Actually, storing the token in the `localStorage` is secure enough and widely used. If you really don't want it, you can use cookies to store the token, but it isn't 100% secure either. Here is an interesting article on the subject : https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage

Comment: Thanks for you comment. The article seems to confirm that local storage is still vulnerable to XSS attacks, where cookies are vulnerable to CSRF attacks. But I believe that the laravel passport framework handles CSRF attacks by the CORS middleware, and that's why I'm interested in storing the token in a cookie, since this together with CORS middleware should make my requests completely secure yes?

Comment: There is also sessionStorage which will empty when the tab closes, which is inherently more secure. If you are still weary about persistence on the client then just keep it in memory.

In your example you don't include a token expiration date, this is another step in increasing security.